# How to refresh a fragment after onbackpressed from activity with kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my android App with Kotlin, I have an interface for user Account that display all his personal information such as FullName, Email, Address ... 
And contains also a button to update user. 
Account is a fragment and when I click on the update Button I go to the UpdateProfile activity.
After I update the user profile, when I click on BackPressed Button to Back to the Account Fragment,the Account Fragment didn't refrech and the new information didn't appear.

So, How to refresh the Account Fragment after onbackpressed from activity ?

I create recreate() function in AccountFragment as follows :

```
fun recreate() {
    val ft: FragmentTransaction = this.fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
    ft.detach(this)
    ft.attach(this)
    ft.commit()
   }
```

and a companion object :

```
companion object {
    lateinit var fragment: AccountFragment
    fun newInstance(): AccountFragment {
        fragment = AccountFragment()
        return fragment
    }
}
```

And, In updateProfile activity, I add in the back press Button a call to recreate funtion :

```
    private var myFragment: AccountFragment = AccountFragment.newInstance()
  override fun onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed()
        myFragment.recreate()
        finish()
    }
```

And, I get the following error :

> ```
> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>     at com.app.fragment.AccountFragment.recreate(AccountFragment.kt:161)
>     at com.app.activity.user.profile.update.UpdateProfile.onBackPressed(UpdateProfile.kt:96)
>     at com.app.activity.user.profile.update.UpdateProfile$onCreate$1.onClick(UpdateProfile.kt:46)
> ```

I would like to know, If my method is correct, If yes How can I correct this error ?

Comment: how to you get the data in the Account Fragment ?

Comment: From a WS I get data

Comment: `Account Fragment` is in other Activity ?

Comment: yes, is in the Main Activity.

Comment: use an interface as a callback in your activity

Comment: I updated my anser, could you please see above

Answer (score 1):

i think you can add `finish()` in activity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
       super.onBackPressed()
       finish()
   }
```

then add refresh on `onResume()` in your fragment

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
         // refresh here 
    }
```

i hope this will help you .